# Bison parsing semantic values

Tags: bison

I have the following code below and I am verifying matching types.  For example relational operations are only being performed using Boolean types.  I have gotten most of that.  I understand that $$ is the result of the operation and $n would be right hand.  But I am confused when I apply it to the function header, I need to make sure that the specified return type is being returned.  Based on my grammar below the return type would $5 but the actual value being returned should be $$.  My question am I applying it to the right part of the grammar and is my logic correct on how to validate that the function is returning the right type?

```
%{

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

#include "types.h"
#include "listing.h"
#include "symbols.h"

int yylex();
void yyerror(const char* message);

Symbols<Types> symbols;
vector<Types> case_statements;
%}

%define parse.error verbose

%union
{
    CharPtr iden;
    Types type;
}

%token <iden> IDENTIFIER
%token <type>INT_LITERAL REAL_LITERAL BOOL_LITERAL NOTOP CASE CASES TRUE FALSE ELSE ENDIF IF

%token ADDOP MULOP RELOP ANDOP EXPOP OROP REMOP
%token BEGIN_ BOOLEAN END ENDREDUCE INTEGER IS FUNCTION REDUCE RETURNS ENDCASE OTHERS REAL THEN WHEN ARROW


%type <type> type function_header statement statement_ reductions expression binary exponent unary relation term factor primary case cases

%%

function:   
    function_header optional_variable body;
    
function_header:    
    FUNCTION IDENTIFIER parameters RETURNS type ';' {checkAssignment($$,$5, "Narrowing Function Returns");}|
    FUNCTION IDENTIFIER RETURNS type ';' {checkAssignment($$,$4, "Narrowing Function Returns");}|
    error ';' ;
    

optional_variable:
    optional_variable variable |
    error ';' |
    ;

variable:   
    IDENTIFIER ':' type IS statement_ 
        {checkAssignment($3, $5, "Variable Initialization");
        {if (symbols.find($1, $3)) appendError(DUPLICATE_IDENTIFIER, $1);
        symbols.insert($1, $3);} };

parameters:
    parameter optional_parameter;
    
optional_parameter:
    optional_parameter ',' parameter|
    ;
    
parameter:
    IDENTIFIER ':' type {symbols.insert($1, $3);}

type:
    INTEGER {$$ = INT_TYPE;} |
    REAL {$$ = REAL_TYPE;} |
    BOOLEAN {$$ = BOOL_TYPE;} ;

body:
    BEGIN_ statement_ END ';' ;
    
statement_:
    statement ';' |
    error ';' {$$ = MISMATCH;} ;
    
statement:
    expression |
    REDUCE operator reductions ENDREDUCE {$$ = $3;} ; |
    IF expression THEN statement_ ELSE statement_ ENDIF {$$ = checkIfThen($$, $4, $6);} |
    CASE expression IS cases OTHERS ARROW statement_ ENDCASE {$$ =checkExpression($2); case_statements.push_back($7);
    int size = case_statements.size();
    if (!case_statements.empty()) {
        int org;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < case_statements.size(); j++) {
                if (org == j) {
                    $$ = checkCases(case_statements[i], case_statements[j]);
                }
            }
            org = i;
        }
    case_statements.clear();
    }
    } ;

operator:
    ADDOP |
    RELOP |
    EXPOP |
    MULOP ;

cases:
    | cases case {$$ = $2;} ;

case:
    WHEN INT_LITERAL ARROW statement_ { case_statements.push_back($4);} ;
    

reductions:
    reductions statement_ {$$ = checkArithmetic($1, $2);} |
    {$$ = INT_TYPE;} ;

expression:
    expression OROP binary {$$ = checkLogical($1, $3);} |
    binary ;

binary:
    binary ANDOP relation {$$ = checkLogical($1, $3);} |
    relation

relation:
    relation RELOP term {$$ = checkRelational($1, $3);}|
    term ;

term:
    term ADDOP factor {$$ = checkArithmetic($1, $3);} |
    factor ;
      
factor:
    factor MULOP primary  {$$ = checkArithmetic($1, $3);} |
    factor REMOP exponent {$$ = checkInteger($1, $3);} |
    exponent ;

exponent:
    unary |
    unary EXPOP exponent {$$ = checkArithmetic($1,$3);};

unary:
    NOTOP primary {$$ = $2;}|
    primary;

primary:
    '(' expression ')' {$$ = $2;} |
    INT_LITERAL |
    REAL_LITERAL |
    IDENTIFIER {if (!symbols.find($1, $$)) appendError(UNDECLARED, $1);} ;
    
%%

void yyerror(const char* message)
{
    appendError(SYNTAX, message);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])    
{
    firstLine();
    yyparse();
    lastLine();
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: Updated the code based on the information below

```
function:   
    function_header optional_variable body {checkAssignment($1,$3, "Narrowing Function Return");};;
    
function_header:    
    FUNCTION IDENTIFIER parameters RETURNS type ';' {$$ = $5;} ;|
    FUNCTION IDENTIFIER RETURNS type ';' {$$ = $4;} ;|
    error ';' {$$ = MISMATCH;};
    

optional_variable:
    optional_variable variable |
    error ';' |
    ;

variable:   
    IDENTIFIER ':' type IS statement_ 
        {checkAssignment($3, $5, "Variable Initialization");
        {if (symbols.find($1, $3)) appendError(DUPLICATE_IDENTIFIER, $1);
        symbols.insert($1, $3);} }

parameters:
    parameter optional_parameter;
    
optional_parameter:
    optional_parameter ',' parameter|
    ;
    
parameter:
    IDENTIFIER ':' type {symbols.insert($1, $3);}

type:
    INTEGER {$$ = INT_TYPE;} |
    REAL {$$ = REAL_TYPE;} |
    BOOLEAN {$$ = BOOL_TYPE;} ;

body:
    BEGIN_ statement_ END ';' {$$ = $2;}
    
statement_:
    statement ';' {$$ = $1;}|
    error ';' {$$ = MISMATCH;} ;
    
statement:
    expression {$$ = $1;}|
    REDUCE operator reductions ENDREDUCE {$$ = $3;} ; |
    IF expression THEN statement_ ELSE statement_ ENDIF {$$ = checkIfThen($1, $4, $6);} |
    CASE expression IS cases OTHERS ARROW statement_ ENDCASE {$$ =checkCaseExpression($2);case_statements.push_back($7);
    int size = case_statements.size();
    if (!case_statements.empty()) {
        int org;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < case_statements.size(); j++) {
                if (org == j) {
                    $$ = checkCases(case_statements[i], case_statements[j]);
                }
            }
            org = i;
        }
    case_statements.clear();
    };} ;

operator:
    ADDOP |
    RELOP |
    EXPOP |
    MULOP ;

cases:
    %empty {$$ = EMPTY; }|
    cases case ;

case:
    WHEN INT_LITERAL ARROW statement_ { case_statements.push_back($4);}|
    %empty {$$ = EMPTY;} ;
```

Checker function

```
void checkAssignment(Types lValue, Types rValue, string message)
{
    if (lValue != MISMATCH && rValue != MISMATCH && lValue != rValue)
        appendError(GENERAL_SEMANTIC, "Type Mismatch on " + message);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every grammar symbol (token or non-terminal) has an associated "semantic" value. The word "semantic" is used to indicate that these values are not syntactic; that is, they are not part of the parse. The bison/yacc parser does not compute these values for you, since it is only concerned with parsing the input. However, it does arrange for two things:

- Semantic values set by the lexical analyser are associated with the corresponding token;
- Whatever code you associate with a production (the "semantic action") is executed when that production is recognised.

It's up to you to write semantic actions which compute the semantic values for those non-terminals whose semantic values are needed in the productions which use them. You do this by *assigning to" the special symbol `$$`, which the parser will use as the semantic value of the non-terminal whose production has been recognised

In a semantic action, you can refer to the semantic values of the grammar symbols on the right-hand side of the production, using the special symbols `$1`, `$2`, etc. The number is the index of the symbol in the right-hand side. If that symbol is a token, its value must have been set by the lexical scanner, by being placed into `yylval`. If the referenced symbol is a non-terminal, the value must be set by *every* production for that non-terminal (whose actions must assign some value to `$$`.

There's a chapter in the Bison manual about [Language semantics](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Semantics) which goes into a lot more details, with examples. (It might help to read the introductory material in that manual first, if you have not already done so.)

For what it's worth, I would suggest not trying to do type-checking during the parse. You'll probably find it easier to *separate concerns*, by constructing a semantic tree ("AST") during the parse, and then doing separate passes over that tree to complete your analysis.

Comment: I added the semantics that I currently have, I'm confused as to where I would compare the types for the whole program.

Comment: @tashao: you could use a recursive depth-first traverse, where every node first calls the type checker recursively on each child to check the type of the child node (and compute the type of the child, if that's meaningful) and then validates the types of its children (if necessary) returning the x9mouted type of the  node (if meaningful).

Comment: Thanks, I was giving the code and needed to add semantics to the grammar. I added the updated code, just in case someone has an issue.  Can I ask you another question, I am trying to compare the when statements within a case.  Currently the code gives the right output but it's comparing it recursively.  In other words, instead of one error, I get three.

Comment: @tasha: there is no recursion in that check. Afaics, the loop in your case statement action checks each consecutive pair of where statements, but perhaps I'm wrong. Also, it's unspecified behaviour because the first time through the loop, `org` is undefined. I honestly think you would find this exercise easier if you followed my suggestion about building an AST, but that's up to you. However you do it, you need to figure out a way to write unit tests for your parse actions, because there are probably other bugs.

Comment: unfortunately this is for a class and most of the code was written for us already.  We were just to add semantics.  But you did point out something that I missed, org being undefined.